# Change retention policy topic kafka

Tags: python, apache-kafka

I want to change a default retention time of one topic to 'rentention.ms=100', but i don't find a solution in python. Can someone help me for this, pleaaaaase ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [confluent-kafka-python](https://docs.confluent.io/current/clients/confluent-kafka-python/index.html#confluent_kafka.admin.AdminClient.alter_configs) alter_configs(), [kafka-python](https://kafka-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/apidoc/KafkaAdminClient.html#kafka.KafkaAdminClient.alter_configs) client is currently broken for alter_configs()

```
from kafka.admin import KafkaAdminClient, ConfigResource

admin_client = KafkaAdminClient(
    bootstrap_servers="localhost:9092", 
    client_id='test'
)

topic_list = []
topic_list.append(ConfigResource(restype='TOPIC', name='your_topic_name', set_config={"retention.ms":"1000"}, described_configs=None, error=None))
admin_client.alter_configs(resources=topic_list, validate_only=False)
```

Note: Any configuration properties that are not included will be reverted to their default values. The retention here is in milliseconds.

Comment: Thank you for this solution. But i have one question, is this going to change a retention time for the same topic or create a new topic with a new retention policy ? beacause i want to change the retention for the same topic without creating a new one

Comment: thank you very much for your help, I will try your solution. :)

Comment: If I set the validate_only=True parameter, I simply change the configuration of my existing topic, and if validate_only=False I create a new topic. ? Thanks for your help :)

Comment: As per the doc in the answer, the validate_only parameter tells the broker to only validate the request if set to true, without altering the configuration. Default: False

Comment: What does `error=None` do here? It doesn't say in the docs